# Importing AndroidX (Jetpack) library into a non AndroidX App

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, androidx, android-jetpack

I'm facing a problem with a library/app compatibility, and I cannot find the solution.

I have a library compiled with V28+ as shown:

```
/* Library graddle file targets to v28 with AndroidX support */
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

It's compiled, and fully functional. Basically, this library contains a Fragment that is exported to the application. 
But, as Androidx compliant library, the fragment extends from

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

So far so good, it is working fine here if I use this library into another AnrdoidX compiled App.

The issue is that I have an Application that targets SDK 27, with no AndroidX support:

```
/* Library gradle file targets to v27 with no AndroidX support */ 
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

When I compile it, I got a bunch of errors (Class file for androidx.... not found), as this example (Here, I'm using the library's Fragment element into the App FragmentManager):

```
public class RadioFragment extends RadioPlayerFragment  {
   ^
    class file for androidx.fragment.app.Fragment not found
...
```

If I edit my gradle.properties file, and add the following lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Then I got, for example:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> Android resource linking failed
>     Output:  /Users/anibal/Development/Proyectos/project/Git/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>     /Users/anibal/Development/Proyectos/MovistarRadio/Git/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>     /Users/anibal/Development/Proyectos/project/Git/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1172: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>     /Users/anibal/Development/Proyectos/project/Git/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1173: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>     error: failed linking references.

So, my question:

Is there a way to use an AndroidX (V28) compiled Library in a lower target app with no AndroidX support?

To change the old app to AndroidX is not an option at this point.

Comment: Did you try changing compile sdk to compileSdkVersion 28,I know your question how make it work for lower version.

Comment: Oh @RameshYankati! You are absolutely right! How didn't I see that!!!! My mistake! Obviously it's not compatible with 27, but uprising the sdkVersion to 28 is not a headache! Thanks for your precise answer!

Comment: No, @RameshYankati. Definitely it doesn't seems to work. 
I think that either the project and the library must be AndroidX compatible. There is no real backwards compatibility with AndroidX and non-X compliant apps. 
Now we will have to maintain either AndroidX and non-androidX code for both version

Comment: You can check this features from official android about versioning.
Unlike the Support Library, AndroidX packages are separately maintained and updated. The androidx packages use strict Semantic Versioning starting with version 1.0.0. You can update AndroidX libraries in your project independently